# Accountant as referee for self-employment proof?

Tags: background-check

I'm having a background check carried out on my 5 year employment history by a third party following a job offer. 3 years ago, I was self-employed for roughly 6 months in my home country which is different from the country I live in now. This means my tax return is in a foreign language so I thought my accountant from back then might be a referee to confirm my activity during that period. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Thanks Joe. Not yet, but I assumed I would be since it falls under my 5 year employment history?

Comment: @Pokie I highly recommend to wait at least 12h before accepting an answer, gives more people an incentive to come and offer a different perspective

Comment: Thanks for heads up Paul. Im new here and not sure how it all works:)

Answer (score 2):

> What are your thoughts?

Explain your situation and ask the people who will be doing the background check, they will tell you exactly what documents they need to confirm the story.

My experience is that someone saying something won't cut it and they will want to see some paperwork which you will have to pay to get translated and the translation certified by notary public or equivalent in your country. It's that or they will simply not care because it's insignificant due to age/length etc.